# table heading not appearing on sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a sample project named **Tennis Club Management** based on HTML,CSS,Javascript.In this i have html pages like **profile.html, manageFees.html,index.js** etc. In **manageFees.html**, when the page gets loaded, a dynamic table gets displayed which shows data from online API in tabular format and there is also a **search box** for searching the records.

**Problem :-** When i search a particular data(record) in search box. the search result gets displayed in the table , **but** the table heading gets disappeared and table CSS properties get distorted.

**Below are the code files and Screenshots**

**index.js**

```
/* --------------------MANAGE FEES PAGE------------------- */



/*----------TESTING CODE FOR SHOW FEES-----------*/

function showfees() {
    console.log("Show Fees button clicked...");
    document.querySelector(".showfees").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#feesregistration").style.display = "none";
    if (istableCreated) {
        document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "none";
    }

    document.querySelector(".searchbox").style.display = "block";
    if (istableCreated == false) {

        istableCreated = true;

        var myTable = document.createElement("table");
        myTable.className = "table-responsive";
        myTable.id = "table-responsive";
        myTable.style.marginLeft = "15%";
        myTable.style.paddingLeft = "8%";
        myTable.style.paddingRight = "11%";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable);

        var maintr = document.createElement("tr");
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr);

        var thmatchID = document.createElement("th");
        thmatchID.innerHTML = "Match ID";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thmatchID);

        var thmatchplayerName = document.createElement("th");
        thmatchplayerName.innerHTML = "Player Name";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thmatchplayerName);

        var thmatchDate = document.createElement("th");
        thmatchDate.innerHTML = "Fees Date";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thmatchDate);

        var thFeesAmount = document.createElement("th");
        thFeesAmount.innerHTML = "Amount";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thFeesAmount);

        var thMembershipType = document.createElement("th");
        thMembershipType.innerHTML = "Membership Type";
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thMembershipType);

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // console.log(this.responseText);
                var JSONarr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(JSONarr);

                // ----------SUPER TESTING CODE-----------

                for (var i = 0; i < JSONarr.length; i++) {
                    console.log(JSONarr[i].id, JSONarr[i].name, JSONarr[i].address.city, JSONarr[i].address.zipcode);

                    var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr);
                    var tdID = document.createElement("td");
                    tdID.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].id}`;
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdID);

                    var tdplayerName = document.createElement("td");
                    tdplayerName.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].name}`;
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdplayerName);

                    var tdAddress = document.createElement("td");
                    tdAddress.innerHTML = `04/04/2020`;
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdAddress);

                    var tdFeesAmount = document.createElement("td");
                    tdFeesAmount.innerHTML = `10000`;
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdFeesAmount);

                    var tdMembershipType = document.createElement("td");
                    tdMembershipType.innerHTML = `Annually`;
                    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdMembershipType);
                }

            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "block";
    }

    if (statictableboolean == true) {
        document.querySelector(".staticTable").style.display = "none";
    }
    // document.querySelector(".staticTable").style.display = "none";
}


//-------------SEARCHING IMPLEMENTATION IN SEARCH BOX----------------

function mySearch() {


    var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
    input = document.getElementById("searchbox");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table-responsive");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
            found = false;
        }
        else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

}
```

**manageFees.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manage Fees</title>

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body onload="showfees()">

    <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW MATCHES, ADD MATCHES USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showfees" onclick="showfees()">Show Fees</button> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addfees" onclick="addfees()">Add Fees</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger showfees" onclick="showfees()">Back</button>
    

    <!-- ADDING SEARCH BAR -->
    <input type="text" class="searchbox" id="searchbox" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="Search by ID...">

    <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION PAGE FOR ADDING FEES -->
    <table class="feesregistration" id="feesregistration">
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>
                <label>ID :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="feesid" id="feesid">
            </td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="playerNameFees" id="playerNameFees" maxlength="40">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playerNameFeeserror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fees For :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="feesFor" id="feesFor">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="court">Court</option>
                    <option value="tournament">Tournament</option>
                    <option value="both">Both</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesForerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fee Type :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="feesType" id="feesType">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="halfyearly">Half Yearly</option>
                    <option value="annually">Annually</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesTypeerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Date :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" class="feesdate">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesdateerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savefees" onclick="saveFees()">SAVE</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info clearfees" onclick="clearfees()">CLEAR</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Dynamic table getting generated using online API with search box]

[image: Searching record with table heading getting disappeared and css getting distorted]

[image: Clearing search box and getting dynamic table again with heading disappeared and css getting distorted]

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: HI Can you add your JS fiddle to show the actual issue you are having ?

Comment: AlwaysHelping : here is the js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/mohitsharma1991/n6Lz0vwo/1/

Comment: Its working fine in the fiddle. the heading is not getting disappeared when i search for a name.

Comment: AlwaysHelping : can you search using ID too...because search by using ID is not working for me ?

Comment: Your question does NOT say anywhere that the problem is search by ID ?

Comment: AlwaysHelping : i managed to hold the table headings and its CSS and can also search using name but unable to search using ID

Comment: I am able to search using ID as well. but ID 1 2, 4 does not work. WHICH is very weird :/

Comment: AlwaysHelping : Let me check the code again ....i will update here as soon as i solve it....thanks for your help and time brother.. :)